# Can I make a nullable variable negative?

Tags: c#

I just want to know if the following syntax is legal in c#:

```
decimal price = -someVariable ?? 0M;
```

Basically, can I make a nullable variable a negative, not knowing if it's null or not?

Comment: `decimal price = Math.Min((somevariable ?? 0M) * -1, (somevariable ?? 0M));`

Comment: Also, the compiler/a test will be sure to tell you yes or no :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That probably isn't because the negative sign would be attached to `someVariable` which could be null, you could wrap the null coalesce in brackets though.

```
decimal price = -(someVariable ?? 0M);
```

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I was wandering.  Thanks.

Comment: This is not correct as if it was null you would end up with 0m and not null.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is legal, if **someVariable** is **null**, **-someVariable** will also be **null**. But for sake of clarity you might want to rewrite it as the following:

```
decimal price = -(someVariable ?? 0M);
```

Another example

```
decimal? a = null;
decimal b = 5;
decimal? c = a + b; // c == null
```